# How many 8-character passwords are there if at least one of each A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 are used?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 8-character passwords are there if each character is either A-Z, a-z, or 0-9, and where at least one character of each of the three types is used?

The complement of "at least one of each" is "either A-Z, a-z, or 0-9 is NOT used"

I defined a set $\left\lvert A\right\rvert=62^8$, all possible passwords. I then defined three more sets: $B$ - those passwords without A-Z, $C$ - those passwords without a-z, and $D$ - those passwords without 0-9.

$$\left\lvert B\right\rvert = 36^8,\quad \left\lvert C\right\rvert=36^8,\quad\mbox{ and } \left\lvert D\right\rvert = 52^8$$

Then by counting the complement, $\left\lvert A\right\rvert - \left\lvert B\cup C\cup D\right\rvert = \left\lvert A\right\rvert-\left\lvert B\right\rvert-\left\lvert C\right\rvert-\left\lvert D\right\rvert + \left\lvert B\cap C\right\rvert + \left\lvert B\cap D\right\rvert + \left\lvert C\cap D\right\rvert$.

$\left\lvert B\cup C\right\rvert ={}$Those without A-Z and without a-z ${}= 10^8$, etc.

Therefore I got $$62^8 - 36^8 - 36^8 - 52^8+ 10^8 + 26^8 + 26^8$$ as the answer.

Not sure if I counted my sets right, please let me know!

Comment: I know my comment is way late, but I just saw this today. Recently I wrote a Monte Carlo simulator to evaluate passwords rules.  It can be easily configured to fit a variety of criteria.  I adjusted it to your criteria and pseudo-randomly generated 10,000,000 passwords.  I used Maxima to evaluate your answer, and obtained 1.5965591136768*10^14  I ran my simulator and obtained 1.598e+14, which agrees with your answer to 3 significant digits.  So your analysis appears to be correct.  Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether order matters or not. Are you allowed to have numbers and letter repeat etc etc. That will dictate on whether you are going to use a permutations or a combination.

Comment: No restrictions - order doesn't matter & repetition allowed

Comment: Bump to Cameron

Comment: @user64025 Order _doesn't_ matter? That's not in line with how real world passwords work. Are you sure? 'password' and 'wordpass' should count as different passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If order matters (so that $12345678$ and $87654321$ would be different passwords, for example) and repetition is allowed, then you've done it exactly right.

If order *doesn't* matter, and repetition is allowed, then we need to proceed differently. We'll need one each from the capital letters, the lower case letters, and the digits, with the other $5$ chosen from the general pool. Hence, the total number in that case is $$26\cdot 26\cdot 10\cdot 62^5.$$

If we *don't* allow repetition, and order doesn't matter, then we have $$\binom{26}{1}\cdot\binom{26}{1}\cdot\binom{10}{1}\cdot\binom{59}{5}$$ options.

I don't want to deal with the case that we don't have repetition and order matters unless I have to, but let me know if that's the circumstance.